# How does mprotect() work?

Tags: c, linux-kernel

I was stracing some of the common commands in the linux kernel, and saw mprotect() was used a lot many times. I'm just wondering, what is the deciding factor that mprotect() uses to find out that the memory address it is setting a protection value for, is in its own address space?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

On architectures with an MMU<sup>1</sup>, the address that `mprotect()` takes as an argument is a virtual address.  Each process has its own independent virtual address space, so there's only two possibilities:

- The requested address is within the process's own address range; or
- The requested address is within the kernel's address range (which is mapped into every process).

`mprotect()` works internally by altering the flags attached to a VMA<sup>2</sup>.  The first thing it must do is look up the VMA corresponding to the address that was passed - if the passed address was within the kernel's address range, then there is *no* VMA, and so this search will fail.  This is exactly the same thing happens if you try to change the protections on an area of the address space that is not mapped.

You can see a representation of the VMAs in a process's address space by examining `/proc/<pid>/smaps` or `/proc/<pid>/maps`.

---

<sup>1. Memory Management Unit</sup>
<sup>2. Virtual Memory Area, a kernel data structure describing a contiguous section of a process's memory</sup>.

Answer (score 3):

This is about [virtual memory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory). And about [dynamic linker/loader](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ld-linux). Most [`mprotect(2)`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/mprotect) syscalls you see in the trace are probably related to bringing in library dependencies, though [`malloc(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/malloc) implementation might call it too.

#### Edit:

To answer your question in comments - the [MMU](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management_unit) and the code inside the kernel protect one process from the other. Each process has an illusion of a full 32-bit or 64-bit address space. The addresses *you* operate on are **virtual** and belong to a given process. Kernel, with the help of the hardware, maps those to **physical** memory pages. These pages could be shared between processes implicitly as code, or explicitly for interprocess communications.

Comment: My question was a bit different. What will stop me from doing a mprotect() on a memory address someother user's process is using?

Comment: You can't do that. mprotect takes an address within the calling process' virtual address space. It's simply not possible to tell mprotect about another process' addresses.

Answer (score 3):

The kernel looks up the address you pass mprotect in the current process's page table.  If it is not in there then it fails.  If it is in there the kernel may attempt to mark the page with new access rights.  I'm not sure, but it may still be possible that the kernel would return an error here if there were some special reason that the access could not be granted (such as trying to change the permissions of a memory mapped shared file area to writable when the file was actually read only).

Keep in mind that the page table that the processor uses to determine if an area of memory is accessible is not the one that the kernel used to look up that address.  The processor's table may have holes in it for things like pages that are swapped out to disk.  The tables are related, but not the same.